# OpenGL render closed transparent objects?

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math, opengl-3

I'm trying to render transparent objects in OpenGL. 
Because transparent objects need to be drawn from back to front.
I created a class for a triangle and store every triangle in a list like this: `std::list<std::pair<float, CoreTriangle*>> *triangles` The float in the pair is the distance between the camera and the smallest vertex of my triangle. The smallest vertex is calculated like this:

```
glm::vec3 CoreTriangle::getMinVertex(glm::vec3 cameraPosition) {
    int i = 0;

    float distance1 = glm::distance(cameraPosition, (modelMat * glm::vec4(vertices[0], 1.0f)).xyz());
    float distance2 = glm::distance(cameraPosition, (modelMat * glm::vec4(vertices[1], 1.0f)).xyz());
    float distance3 = glm::distance(cameraPosition, (modelMat * glm::vec4(vertices[2], 1.0f)).xyz());

    if(distance1 < distance2 && distance1 < distance3) {
        i = 0;
    }
    else if(distance2 < distance1 && distance2 < distance3) {
        i = 1;
    }
    else if(distance3 < distance1 && distance3 < distance2) {
        i = 2;
    }

    return (modelMat * glm::vec4(vertices[i], 1.0f)).xyz();
}
```

In every render cycle I set the float of the pair using this command:

```
for(std::list<std::pair<float, CoreTriangle*>>::iterator it = triangles.begin(); it != triangles.end(); it++) {
      it->first = glm::distance(cam.getEyePosition(), it->second->getMinVertex(cam.getEyePosition()));
}
```

Then I sort the list using the `sort` function of the list.

Now I render the sorted list from back to front using this commands:

```
for(std::list<std::pair<float, CoreTriangle*>>::reverse_iterator it = triangles.rbegin(); it != triangles.rend(); it++) {
      it->second->render();
}
```

I have a few triangles in a row that look like this:

[image]

This all seams to work for single triangles that don't intersect

But then I tried to render a transparent cube and it looks like this:

[image]
[image]
[image]

So at some positions the triangles aren't rendered in the right order. How can this be fixed?

Comment: The corner which is closest to the camera, is shared by multiple triangles. It may help to sort the triangles with "equal" distance by its normal vector. But note, to "sort" 2 triangles, you would have to evaluate if any of the 6 rays to the corners of the triangles intersects the other triangle. Event then there are still cases where this test fails.

Comment: @Rabbid76 what do you mean with sorting by the normal vector? Do you mean that instead of the vertices then the normals should be using in the sorting?

Comment: No, not instead. Additionally, if the distances are equal.

Comment: @Rabbid76 ok, do you know any way that this could be done with my list, without going over every element and checking if they are equal?

Comment: @Rabbid76 I'm trying to implement that, should I use only the normals or vertices + normals?

Comment: No, you have to sort it by the angle of the normal vector in relation to the line of sight. Something like `dot(normal,(0,0,-1)`. (`dot` is the [Dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product)). But note in general you would have to find the intersection line of the 2 planes with are defined by the 3 triangles. Then you have to sort the triangles dependent on there location relative to the line.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I don't really get it. Can you please describe your algorithm completely?

Comment: @user11914177: sort by the distance to the triangle barycenter instead (`(v0 + v1 + v2)/3`). It's simpler and should fix your problem.

Comment: That being said, you should acknowledge that any way of triangle sorting will never solve the problem completely, only fail for another set of cases.

Comment: @ybungalobill This makes everything worse, nether the cube nor the triangles work now! 
How can a simple game like Minecraft render transparent triangles if there isn't an algorithm?

Comment: if it became worse then there must be some other issue (please post the code you tried, maybe I can figure it out). Minecraft doesn't need to sort anything because it's already arranged in a data-structure that can be traversed back to front -- though frankly I didn't play Minecraft and don't know what they do. There are algorithms for rendering transparent objects, but they are  based on per-fragment sorting, and thus are much more heavy and complicated. Other alternatives including using a commutative blending operator, or subdividing your big triangles with back-face culling enabled.

Comment: @ybungalobill So I sort my objects now using the distance between the camera position and the average of all my vertices multiplied with my model matrix. I calculate the latter using this command: `(modelMat * glm::vec4(vertices[0] + vertices[1] + vertices[2], 1.0f)).xyz() / 3.0f`. The errors are, that the cube still doesn't work and my line of triangles doesn't work when getting close to it (this didn't happen with my approach)